# How to test pedometer in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

How can I simulate stepping activity in xCode iOS Simulator? or my only option to test on a real iPhone 5S+?

Answer (score 3):

The simulator has no accelerometer and hence you can only test it on a real device